# Name / notation for the set of all distinct combinations of elements from a set of a certain size?

Tags: combinatorics, notation, combinations

Suppose I have a set $A$ which contains $N$ distinct elements.  Suppose I want to obtain the set $B$ of all sets of distinct combinations of size $K$ from set $A$.  Is there a name for this set $B$?  Allow me to give an example:

Suppose $A = \lbrace 1, 2, 3 \rbrace $ and $K = 2$.

Clearly $N=3$ since A contains three distinct elements.

So then $B$ = $\lbrace \lbrace 1, 2\rbrace ,\lbrace 1, 3 \rbrace, \lbrace 2, 3 \rbrace \rbrace$

Is there a name for $B$?  If not, what's a concise way to define this set?

Comment: They are just $K$-element subsets.  The number of such subsets is $\binom{N}{K} = \frac{N!}{K!(N - K)!}$, the number of $K$-combinations of an $N$ element set.

Answer (score 3):

A fairly common notation for this is $B=\binom{A}{K}$.  This is by analogy with the notation $\binom{N}{K}$ for the cardinality of $B$: we replace $N$ by a set $A$ with $N$ elements, and correspondingly take the set of all subsets with $K$ elements, rather than just counting how many there are.

The notation $B=[A]^K$ is also used, though this is used mainly in set theory where $A$ is typically an infinite set (and $K$ may be taken to be an infinite cardinal as well).